# Which sci fi film has what appears to be Guardians of the Galaxy characters doing scavenging and robbing an elevated air train?

Tags: story-identification, movie

This could be 2 separate films, but I know in one of the scenes a scavenger group in an open scooter is trying to make a getaway, not taking any hitchhikers because it would get too heavy.

In another scene they are robbing an elevated air train carrying some valuable material (vials of something), when one character gets pinned by one of the gun turrets and can't get free.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're conflating two different films:

- **Serenity**: The crew of the Serenity are engaged in a bank heist using a large open hoversled. They can't rescue any locals from an attack due to the weight restriction on their vehicle.

  **<sub>Warning: NSFW - Gore / Bad Language</sub>**
- **Solo: A Star Wars Story**: Tobias Beckett and his crew (including the eponymous Han Solo) are robbing a train. Beckett's right-hand-gal/lover Val is killed when she gets pinned down behind a pillar.

  **<sub>Warning: NSFW - Not Very Well Written</sub>**

Comment: I feel old if _Solo: A Star Wars Story_ is already getting forgetful Story-ID q’s.

Comment: @SillybutTrue - That's because anyone who watched it at home was playing with their mobile by this point

Comment: To increase confusion, *Serenity* is a continuation of *Firefly*. *Firefly's* original pilot episode, "[The Train Job](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Train_Job)", has the characters stealing from a levitated, but not elevated, train. Unbeknownst to them, they are stealing vials of medicine. So, it could be that the OP is thinking of *Serenity* and "Firefly: The Train Job" which both have the same characters. However, for the OP's "one character gets pinned by one of the gun turrets", Solo is a better match, but "The Train Job" does have a character pinned by weapons fire, but in a different way.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just realized that is was from Solo : A Start Wars Story.

But I could not remember the first scene, yes Serenity is the one!

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Might you be thinking of the train heist in [*Solo: a Star Wars Story*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story)?

> Beckett, aware of the usefulness of a Wookiee's strength, rescues and enlists them in the gang to steal a shipment of coaxium on Vandor-1. The plan fails when the Cloud Riders, a band of marauders led by Enfys Nest, arrive to hijack the shipment. The resulting chaos leads to the destruction of the coaxium and the deaths of Beckett's wife Val and their crewman Rio.